# What is "SwarmPackagePy.cso.cso at 0x187cf21e340"

Tags: optimization

```
def rosen(x):
"""The Rosenbrock function"""
return sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0)**2.0 + (1-x[:-1])**2.0)

from SwarmPackagePy import cso

cso(1,rosen,10,1000,2,10000,pa=0.25,nest=100)
```

---

```
Out[41]: <SwarmPackagePy.cso.cso at 0x187cf21e340>
```

How can I access outputs of cso function? There aren't docs on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a "data science" question but more of a "(Python) programming" question. You can find more comprehensive answers at stackoverflow.

Other than that, if you go to the source code of [SwarmPackagePy.cso](https://github.com/SISDevelop/SwarmPackagePy/blob/master/SwarmPackagePy/cso.py) (I was not able to find any documentation), you will see that it creates an instance (object) of the `cso` class and what you get when you print this object is the location or address of this object in the memory.

Comment: so how do I access outputs of cso function?

Comment: You can use the dot notation (sth like `your_class.attribute_name`) to access the attributes. There might be methods defined that operate on this class. I have to add that, some of these attributes are not there to be accessed by users of the package but just used internally, so be warned!